# Revoke all tokens except one after log in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, doorkeeper

doorkeeper.rb

```
Doorkeeper.configure do
  # Change the ORM that doorkeeper will use (needs plugins)
  orm :active_record

  # This block will be called to check whether the resource owner is authenticated or not.
  resource_owner_authenticator do
    fail "Please configure doorkeeper resource_owner_authenticator block located in #{__FILE__}"
    # Put your resource owner authentication logic here.
    # Example implementation:
    #   User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) || redirect_to(new_user_session_url)
  end
  #Make by phone instead email
  resource_owner_from_credentials do |_routes|
    if params[:scope].present?
      case params[:scope]
        when "passenger"
          PassengerUser.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
        when "driver"
          DriverUser.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
      end
    else 
      PassengerUser.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
    end
  end

  grant_flows %w(password)

  skip_authorization do
    true
  end

  # If you want to restrict access to the web interface for adding oauth authorized applications, you need to declare the block below.
  # admin_authenticator do
  #   # Put your admin authentication logic here.
  #   # Example implementation:
  #   Admin.find_by_id(session[:admin_id]) || redirect_to(new_admin_session_url)
  # end

  # Authorization Code expiration time (default 10 minutes).
  # authorization_code_expires_in 10.minutes

  # Access token expiration time (default 2 hours).
  # If you want to disable expiration, set this to nil.
  # access_token_expires_in 2.hours

  # Assign a custom TTL for implicit grants.
  # custom_access_token_expires_in do |oauth_client|
  #   oauth_client.application.additional_settings.implicit_oauth_expiration
  # end

  # Use a custom class for generating the access token.
  # https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper#custom-access-token-generator
  # access_token_generator '::Doorkeeper::JWT'

  # The controller Doorkeeper::ApplicationController inherits from.
  # Defaults to ActionController::Base.
  # https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper#custom-base-controller
  # base_controller 'ApplicationController'

  # Reuse access token for the same resource owner within an application (disabled by default)
  # Rationale: https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/issues/383
  #reuse_access_token

  # Issue access tokens with refresh token (disabled by default)
  use_refresh_token

  # Provide support for an owner to be assigned to each registered application (disabled by default)
  # Optional parameter confirmation: true (default false) if you want to enforce ownership of
  # a registered application
  # Note: you must also run the rails g doorkeeper:application_owner generator to provide the necessary support
  # enable_application_owner confirmation: false

  # Define access token scopes for your provider
  # For more information go to
  # https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Using-Scopes
  default_scopes :passenger

  optional_scopes :driver

  # Change the way client credentials are retrieved from the request object.
  # By default it retrieves first from the `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` header, then
  # falls back to the `:client_id` and `:client_secret` params from the `params` object.
  # Check out https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Changing-how-clients-are-authenticated
  # for more information on customization
  # client_credentials :from_basic, :from_params

  # Change the way access token is authenticated from the request object.
  # By default it retrieves first from the `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` header, then
  # falls back to the `:access_token` or `:bearer_token` params from the `params` object.
  # Check out https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Changing-how-clients-are-authenticated
  # for more information on customization
  # access_token_methods :from_bearer_authorization, :from_access_token_param, :from_bearer_param

  # Change the native redirect uri for client apps
  # When clients register with the following redirect uri, they won't be redirected to any server and the authorization code will be displayed within the provider
  # The value can be any string. Use nil to disable this feature. When disabled, clients must provide a valid URL
  # (Similar behaviour: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp#choosingredirecturi)
  #
  # native_redirect_uri 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'

  # Forces the usage of the HTTPS protocol in non-native redirect uris (enabled
  # by default in non-development environments). OAuth2 delegates security in
  # communication to the HTTPS protocol so it is wise to keep this enabled.
  #
  # Callable objects such as proc, lambda, block or any object that responds to
  # #call can be used in order to allow conditional checks (to allow non-SSL
  # redirects to localhost for example).
  #
  # force_ssl_in_redirect_uri !Rails.env.development?
  #
  # force_ssl_in_redirect_uri { |uri| uri.host != 'localhost' }

  # Specify what redirect URI's you want to block during creation. Any redirect
  # URI is whitelisted by default.
  #
  # You can use this option in order to forbid URI's with 'javascript' scheme
  # for example.
  #
  # forbid_redirect_uri { |uri| uri.scheme.to_s.downcase == 'javascript' }

  # Specify what grant flows are enabled in array of Strings. The valid
  # strings and the flows they enable are:
  #
  # "authorization_code" => Authorization Code Grant Flow
  # "implicit"           => Implicit Grant Flow
  # "password"           => Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant Flow
  # "client_credentials" => Client Credentials Grant Flow
  #
  # If not specified, Doorkeeper enables authorization_code and
  # client_credentials.
  #
  # implicit and password grant flows have risks that you should understand
  # before enabling:
  #   http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6819#section-4.4.2
  #   http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6819#section-4.4.3
  #
  # grant_flows %w[authorization_code client_credentials]

  # Hook into the strategies' request & response life-cycle in case your
  # application needs advanced customization or logging:
  #
  # before_successful_strategy_response do |request|
  #   puts "BEFORE HOOK FIRED! #{request}"
  # end
  #
  # after_successful_strategy_response do |request, response|
  #   puts "AFTER HOOK FIRED! #{request}, #{response}"
  # end

  # Under some circumstances you might want to have applications auto-approved,
  # so that the user skips the authorization step.
  # For example if dealing with a trusted application.
  # skip_authorization do |resource_owner, client|
  #   client.superapp? or resource_owner.admin?
  # end

  # WWW-Authenticate Realm (default "Doorkeeper").
  # realm "Doorkeeper"
end

Doorkeeper.configuration.token_grant_types << "password"
```

migration:

```
class CreateDoorkeeperTables < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :oauth_access_tokens do |t|
      t.integer  :resource_owner_id
      t.integer  :application_id
      t.string   :token,                  null: false
      t.string   :refresh_token
      t.integer  :expires_in
      t.datetime :revoked_at
      t.datetime :created_at,             null: false
      t.string   :scopes
    end

    add_index :oauth_access_tokens, :token, unique: true
    add_index :oauth_access_tokens, :resource_owner_id
    add_index :oauth_access_tokens, :refresh_token, unique: true
    add_foreign_key(
      :oauth_access_tokens,
      :passenger_users,
      column: :resource_owner_id
    )
  end
end
```

Is it possible revoke all tokens of user after log in? (except new one created after log in) User should be able use app only from one device.

Answer (score 0):

As was answered in [original issue](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/issues/1135) for those who will search similar on SO:

How about something like this in `resource_owner_from_credentials` (or whatever authenticator you use):

```
resource_owner_from_credentials do |_routes|
  owner = if params[:scope].present?
    case params[:scope]
      when "passenger"
        PassengerUser.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
      when "driver"
        DriverUser.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
    end
  else 
    PassengerUser.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
  end

  Doorkeeper::AccessToken.where(resource_owner_id: owner.id).delete_all # it will remove all the tokens for this user, and a new one will be created after this method finish

  owner
end
```

The only thing you need to know is in case you are using different models as resource owners you could face a problem when `AccessToken` was granted for `Admin #1` and other token for `Passanger #1` (both tokens will be removed). In this case you could add an additional field to `Doorkeeper::AccessToken` model and patch it and maybe some internal gem classes to store required information about resource owner model name.